$\sum_n a_n/n$, $\sum_n a_n/n^\rho$, $\sum_n a_n$… Tauberian theorems?
In analytic number theory, it is common to prove that $$\sum_{n\leq N} \frac{a_n}{n} = o(\log N)\tag{$\star$}\label{476699_star}$$ for some sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, $a_n\in \mathbb{C}$. (It is common to call $a_n$ an "arithmetic function"; that just means "a function from $\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ interesting to number theorists".)
It is easy to see that this is weaker than $\sum_{n\leq N} a_n = o(N)$ (strictly weaker; there is a standard counterexample for which $\sum_n a_n n^{-s}$ has a pole at some $s$ with $s\ne 1$, $\Re s = 1$). A few questions suggest themselves.
(a) How does the form of summation above (let's call it "logarithmic summation") stack up against Cesàro summation? We would like to say that \eqref{476699_star} implies $$\sum_{n\leq N} \frac{N-n}{N} a_n = o(N),\tag{$+$}\label{476699_+}$$
but that is not actually true without further conditions (see a counterexample in the comments). What Abel summation actually shows here is that \eqref{476699_star} implies $\sum_{n\leq N} \frac{N-n}{N} a_n = o(N \log N)$. Under what additional conditions would \eqref{476699_star} actually imply \eqref{476699_+}?
Would a similar request be unrealistic if we switched \eqref{476699_star} and \eqref{476699_+}? In other words: is there some well-defined way in which \eqref{476699_+} is farther from being stronger than \eqref{476699_star} than \eqref{476699_star} is from being stronger than \eqref{476699_+}?
(b) More ambitiously: are there interesting Tauberian theorems for going from \eqref{476699_star} to $\sum_{n\leq N} a_n = o(N)$? (That is — are there reasonable additional conditions under which such an implication holds?)
(c) What about Tauberian theorems to go from $\sum_{n\leq N} a_n/n$ to  $\sum_{n\leq N} a_n/n^\rho$ for $0<\rho<1$, and from $\sum_{n\leq N} a_n/n^\rho$ to $\sum_{n\leq N} a_n$? What are some examples of sequences for which $\sum_{n\leq N} a_n/n = o(\log N)$ but $\sum_{n\leq N} a_n/n^\rho$ is not $o(N^{1-\rho})$, or for which $\sum_{n\leq N} a_n/n^\rho = o(N^{1-\rho})$ but $\sum_{n\leq N} a_n$ is not $o(N)$?
I am thinking of $a_n$ bounded or growing slowly ($a_n = O(\log^C n)$), so, if possible, give examples with $a_n$ bounded or growing slowly. I am not thinking of $a_n$ as being positive-real-valued.

Silly comment, but since you say "I am not thinking of $a_n$ as being positive-real-valued," for any of these statements to make sense literally you must be taking absolute value of the sum, right?

@SamHopkins Well, sure, in my definition, $f(x)=o(g(x))$ is the same as $|f(x)|=o(g(x))$. Is that not the case for you? At any rate, I was trying to avoid overly easy Tauberian theorems that assume $a_n\geq 0$. Those are not so interesting in this context, since what one is looking for in practice is cancellation.

The claim about "stronger than Cesaro" looks fishy. Let's take $a_m=m\log m$ for some huge $m$ and the rest $a_n=0$. Then $\left|\sum_{n\le N}\frac{a_n}n\right|\le \log N$ for all $N$, but the Cesaro sum with $N=2m$ is $\frac m2\log m=\frac N4\log\frac N2\gg N$. What am I missing?

@fedya You are quite right that one cannot make that factor of $\log$ disappear without further conditions. What partial summation gives us is that, for $A_C(N) = \sum_{n\leq N} \frac{N-n}{N} a_n$ (the Cesàro mean) and $B(x) = \sum_{n\leq x} a_n/n$, we have $A_C(N) = N \int_0^1 (2 t - 1) B(t N) dt$. What we really want is that $B(x) = o(\log x)$ implies $A_C(N) = o(N)$, and as your example shows, that is not true without further assumptions.

If $a_n = O(1)$, $(+)$ does imply $(\star)$, in that $(+)$ implies even $\sum_{n\leq x} a_n = o(x)$.

Self-comment: I'm afraid Cesàro weights are a bit of a red herring here, in that, for $a_n$ bounded, one can go from non-trivial bounds on Cesàro means to non-trivial bounds on the usual means (at a cost, but bounds of type $o(\text{trivial})$ still imply bounds of type $o(\text{trivial})$).
